# Добавление рекламы в приложение без Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, admob, реклама

Доброго времени суток уважаемые! У меня возник такой вопрос. Я пишу android приложение. Приложение к сожалению скорее всего не может быть размещено в Google play, а если и будет там размещено то скорее всего его оттуда вскоре удалят так как оно предназначено для скачивания музыки из ВК. Я понимаю что распространение приложения через альтернативные источники типа Yandex Store или 4PDA вряд ли принесет много скачиваний но это отдельный вопрос. Главный же вопрос звучит так: смогу ли я встроить в него рекламу (в частности AвMob), если приложения не будет на Google Play? Возможно мой вопрос покажется глупым, просто никогда еще не занимался подобными вещами. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, *Admob* никоем образом не относится конкретно к *Google Play*. Даже больше скажу: *AdMob* можно внедрять даже в *IOS* приложения или *Windows Phone*. Для этого вам необходимо создать акаунт к гугл, прикрепить его к *AdMob* (Всё это бесплатно и быстро делается). Далее почитайте офф. [инструкцию](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start). Сам делал по ней когда-то. Если совсем непонятно, то можете создать новый проект и в качестве шаблона первой Activity выбрать AdMob activity

Answer (score 2):

Да, сможете . так даже лучше, ведь при блокировке в маркете ( неизбежно с такой прогой) показ рекламы на телефонах с уже установленным приложением тоже прекращаеться